# Parse database web front end Javascript script

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am pretty new to javascript having used wordpress for my previous website. I am designing a web fronted for a database on parse. I have set up a test database and have parse hosting it, but I cannot seem to get the javascript to execute and show the data from the database. Any ideas?

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Parse JavaScript Data Retreival App</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.13.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

      <b>Here are some cool stats</b>
      <Ul id="animal-list"></Ul>

          <script type="text/javascript">
             $(function(){
                  Parse.initialaze("zfeUXRI2m0L889lQK2qwfNVDPJHQCVvuYWnew98Q",       
                                   "kW0F3UA51xJluDiFJRPHIf8EJMxfUmZPz3yxFzOi");
                //Get the Animal column data
                var Animals = Parse.Object.extend("Animals");
                var AnimalCollection = Parse.Collection.extend({model: Animals});
                var animalCollection = new AnimalCollection();

                animalCollection.fetch({
                   success: function(collection) {
                      collection.each(function(object) {
                         $("#animal-list").append("<li>") + 
                         object.get("type") + 
                         "</li>");
                      });
                   },
                   error: function(collection, error) {
                      alert(error);
                   }
                })   
             });         
      </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you could provide a more detailed description on what the expected behavior is supposed to be.

Comment: I would like it to load a list from the database called Animals from the type column I have set up that contains a list of animals (think it is Frog, Horse, Lion)

Comment: while editing your code and counting your paren, it looks like `collection.each(function(object) {
                         $("#animal-list").append("<li>") + 
                         object.get("type") + 
                         "</li>");
                      });` should not be finished with a `)` as there seems to be no matching one. I am no javascript expert, but this might be the problem

Comment: Well, I'm no jQuery expert but I don't understand what $(function() { ... }); is suposed to be dong. I would use (function() { ... })(); to invoke the function literal and execute your code.